# Flutter Web: How to disable backward button of browser in flutter web application

Tags: web, flutter

After successfully login the user redirected to the Home page but when the user clicks on the browser back button it easily redirected to the login screen. What should I do to disable backward redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Hope WillPopScope will do the job for you.
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => null,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('asd'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working well, but when i  refreshing page same issue,it redirecting to login screen.

Comment: login is my initialRoute.

Comment: @Olance You can check this https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html to help storing session

Comment: I have the same problem. This is not working for me. `onWillPop` does fire when I use the browser back button on my Flutter Web app. Any to prevent going back to login screen?

Answer (score 1):

**Updating @FederickJonathan answer for 2023, now you have to return a bool value for onWillPop argument like this:**

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Hope WillPopScope will do the job for you.
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false, // update here
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('asd'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And you can also wrap it on MaterialApp class in main.dart to work for whole application at once like this:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: MaterialApp(
       ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```