# How to configure go back button in Browser for Flutter Web App

Tags: flutter, web-applications, flutter-web

I'm not asking about webview. This is about Flutter web app. I need to go back to a specific page when user press back button which is inbuilt in browser.

[image]

Any guessing  ?

I'm getting this error when I press  back button

```
Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang- 
    sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/history.dart:110:14 
    _userProvidedRouteName != null
    is not true
        at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:8300/dart_sdk.js:4770:11)
        at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:8300/dart_sdk.js:4721:15)
```

Comment: have you tried `WillPopScope()` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763779/flutter-web-how-to-disable-backward-button-of-browser-in-flutter-web-applicatio

Comment: I'm getting this error

Comment: Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/history.dart:110:14
_userProvidedRouteName != null
is not true
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:8300/dart_sdk.js:4770:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:8300/dart_sdk.js:4721:15)

Comment: please share your code, if its not working :)

Comment: Please provide the solution as well. if it is working @FaslurRajah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onWillPop` Navigate to a new Page

```
class webScope extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new NewPageWidget())),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("webScope"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In case if you don't want to navigate to a new page

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => true,
      child: Scaffold(

        key: _scaffold,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                registerForm(),
                registerBtn(),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                _buildSignInButton()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work for [Rony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67325662/3935156) and [Umut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70125238/3935156), as well as myself?

Answer (score 4):

```
onWillPop: () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  return new Future(() => true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to emulate the browser back button from within a pushed route in your Flutter web app, I have achieved this via use of Router.neglect:

```
AppBar(
        leading: GestureDetector(
          child: const Icon(Icons.close_rounded, color: Colors.white),
          onTap: () => Router.neglect(context, () => context.pop()),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

For disable this chrome back button you can use

```
 onWillPop: () {
  exit(0);
  return new Future(() => true);
}
```

and for hand back press for back page you can use willPop:

```
 WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YOUROLDPAGE()),
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Home Page"),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy  Caney for your feedback. Its my updated code please check.