# How to handle back button of browser in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-web

this question had already asked in this link [How to configure go back button in Browser for Flutter Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322093/how-to-configure-go-back-button-in-browser-for-flutter-web-app)
and I implement onWillPop, so when user is in A screen and then click the button `See Detail` I will navigate them to B screen and then.. when user is in B screen and click the back button of browser I will navigate them back to A screen... the first trial is success but when I do it second time I got an error like this

```
Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/navigation/history.dart:288:14
_userProvidedRouteName != null
is not true
```

in my first screen (A Screen), I have a button like this:

```
FlatButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (BuildContext ctx) =>
                                                      Detail(
                                                          value:x[i])));
                                        },
                                        child: Text("See Detail"),
                                        textColor: Colors.white,
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                      )
```

and for the Detail Screen (B Screen) I use onWillPop like this

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => FirstScreen()));
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          key: _globalKey,
....
```

is there something that I should add more?

Comment: `FirstScreen` is your app home page ?

Comment: no, First Screen here is screen before I click the button...( screen that consist of button See Detail above)

Comment: I have edited my question for the detail explanation

Comment: @uyhaW could you fix this ?

Comment: @Mary Hi.. sorry for my late response, I can't fix it so I use another method

Answer (score -2):

Call `Navigator.pop(context);` inside the `onWillPop` of screen **B**.

Make sure when you navigate from **Screen A** to **Screen B**, you should not use `Navigator.pushReplacement` as it removes ScreenA from the **screen stack**(not sure if this is the right term)

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()),
  );
```

Here is an example by flutter.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics