# Web control browser back button

Tags: browser, flutter-web, back-button, flutter-navigation

I'm using Navigation 2 and `setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());`
I added `WillPopScope` but the `onWillPop` is not called when clicking the browser's back button.

```
  Widget build(context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    print('here');
    if (currentStep == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: Scaffold(...
```

Comment: This is a very important question. `WillPopScope` works as expected when clicking the `AppBar` back button but does nothing when the browser's native back button is clicked. From the user's perspective, these are 2 identical interactions yet the app behaves differently. I tried connecting down to the javascript and using `onBeforeUnload` but it's never triggered. Perhaps because of Navigation 2, Auto Route, etc. using the history and not really unloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

In Navigator 2.0, [web browsers are chronological](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109011#issuecomment-1212533001) and basically treat all navigation as pushes.

Scenario:

1. Navigate from screen 1 to screen 2
2. Click the browser's back button.

In this scenario, Flutter will *push* the previous route (screen 1) onto the stack.

In other words, the browser back button no longer triggers onPopRoute. Instead it triggers onPushRoute.

I believe it was designed this way so that every navigation action can be treated as a deeplink. With that in mind, if you're developing a Flutter app for the web you should avoid passing arguments from one route to another as much as possible.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71122#issuecomment-733864359