# Willpopscope doesn't work on Web to intercept browsers back button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have tried intercepting back button on web. But it doesn't get triggered.

How can I make it work ?

```
 WillPopScope(
                            onWillPop: () {
                              print("will pop on web");
                              Get.offNamed("/orders");
                              return new Future(() => true);
                            },
                            child: Scaffold(...
```

Comment: Me too. Any luck?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins I didn't find answer for Willpopscope but you can create a global interceptor with using https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor package.

Comment: Cheers, however that [doesn't work for the web browser back button](https://github.com/marcglasberg/back_button_interceptor/issues/13)